# Create function script(spaces preceeding, character selected, and times printed)

Tags: c

I have an attempt, but this site will not let me indent it properly and I keep getting errors
Write the prototype for a function called script that has three input parameters.
The first parameter will be the number of spaces to display at the beginning of a
line. The second parameter will be the character to display after the spaces, and
the third parameter will be the number of times to display the second parameter
on the same line.

```
    script();

    int main() {

        script();

        return 0;

    }

    double script() {

    int spaces, timesCharacter;
    char character;

    printf("Please enter in order the number of spaces preceeding a character\n");
    printf("the specific character to input and \n");
    printf("the number of times your want the character to display\n");
    printf("in order with a space in between each one: \n");

    scanf("%d %c %d", &spaces, &character, &timesCharacter);

    printf("%d %c %d", spaces, character, timesCharacter);

   }
```

this line above is the problem line, I cannot figure out how to print spaces preceeding

Answer (score 1):

> Write the prototype for a function called script that has three input
>   parameters.
>
> how to print spaces preceding?

Function with parameter and Prototype, Have look at follow code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double script(int spaces,char character, int timesCharacter );   //Function Prototype

int main() {

        int spaces, timesCharacter;
        char character;

        script(spaces, character,timesCharacter);  //Function Call 

        return 0;

}

double script(int spaces,char character, int timesCharacter) {  //Function Defination



        printf("Please enter in order the number of spaces preceeding a character\n");
        printf("the specific character to input and \n");
        printf("the number of times your want the character to display\n");
        printf("in order with a space in between each one: \n");

        scanf("%d %c %d", &spaces, &character, &timesCharacter);

        //printf("%d %c %d", spaces, character, timesCharacter);

        /*How to add spaces preceding*/
         printf("%*c", spaces, character);
        //To print the number of times
        int i=0;
        for(i = 1;i < timesCharacter; i++ ){
             printf("%c",character);
        }

}
```

this will not have any error.